# image jpg data inside object element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to correctly embed jpg using `<object>` element.

While using `<object>` with svg data works all fine, but when I put a jpg file into data, the image is not showing correctly.

```
<section class="sidebar" id="sidebar-left">                          

    <object id="sidebar-img" > sidebar </object>                   

</section>
```

I'm injecting images through a javascript on my sub-pages.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#sidebar-img').attr('data', './img/tools.jpg'); 
        $('#sidebar-img').attr('type', 'image/jpg');
    });

</script>
```

Also the browser in the place of jpg `<object>` inserts whole html document tree, html > head > body > [img]  (see the screenshot), with svg data, there's no such thing?

this 'html' height is equal to jpg height, but object has different?

[image]

Have You any idea what is this all about? CSS:

```
.sidebar {

            width: 25%;
            font-size: 120%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
    }

#sidebar-img {

            max-width: 80%;
            height: auto;
            width: auto;
    }
```

Comment: images need to be within <img> tags, you can inject the src= for the image using js

Comment: I know, but I want to use an <object> element here.  My source are jpgs and svgs , I want and object in case, I would like to animate an svg one. 

Do You know how to do this correctly using an object?

Comment: Can you explain *why* exactly you want to use `object` instead of `img`? Is this just an exercise or does it have a practical goal?

Comment: I use <img> for now and it works , but I'm thinking forward, I would like to use an <object>, because with it I can manipulate the svg DOM tree (animate with script), and with <img> I can't do this.

Comment: I could replace an <img> with <object> in such cases, but It would be nice to have just one tag for both situations (jpgs and animated svgs)

Comment: svg's can be used as the src within img, you can script the svg animation within the svg, or you could just directly embed the svg within page

Comment: FWIW what you're trying to do works in Firefox, but not in Chrome or IE. Not sure why. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/r1zghj2t/4/) that might give people ideas.